# TeenyStatisticsWarning on Google Cloud Run

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-run

I got a Cloud Run service written in NodeJS that acts as a WebSocket server. Every couple hours I'm experiencing a sharp high peak of memory usage that causes the instances to drop, and I cannot understand why.

Specifically, I can see the following from the log:

```
(node:1) TeenyStatisticsWarning: Possible excessive concurrent requests detected. 5000 requests in-flight, which exceeds the configured threshold of 5000. Use the TEENY_REQUEST_WARN_CONCURRENT_REQUESTS environment variable or the concurrentRequests option of teeny-request to increase or disable (0) this warning.

(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

Memory limit of 1024 MiB exceeded with 1026 MiB used. Consider increasing the memory limit, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/memory-limits
```

I am using a bunch of GCP SDKs (Firebase Auth, Storage, BigQuery) and it might be that some of them are using [teeny-request](https://github.com/googleapis/teeny-request) under the hood (first log).

I got a feeling that for a short period of time my service cannot execute HTTP requests, and I cannot understand why.

What are my options to debug this?

Comment: The first action item is to increase memory from 1024 MB to 2048 MB (2 GB). I would also increase the number of CPUs to at least two. Then retest.

Comment: To quickly mitigate the issue, yes. But the average memory consumption is around 20% (of 1024MB), so I'm looking also to solve the issue without memory increase.

Comment: You have 5,000 requests in-flight. Reduce the number of requests that your application is making. The issue is with your design and not Cloud Run. I still recommend increasing the memory. Never allow an out-of-memory situation to occur. Your options are to either improve your application design or use a larger instance size.

Comment: In my current workload, 5,000 requests in-flight are not expected. I'm looking for a way to debug this and understand what's causing this. What are the best practices here?

Comment: Include a minimum reproducible example in your post. Until then, there are no best practices as we must guess. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example